# Getting dashboard name

Tags: sql, oracle, obiee

I want to write a ticker in Oracle BI that perceives the name of different dashboards.

I know that there's a "Presentation Variable System" in OBI where I can get different information from the dashboards. I found an example on a website where they solve it like this:

@{dashboard.currentPage}

It doesn't work for me.

Comment: _What_ doesn't work? How are you using this? Do you have any error messages? What do you expect to happen? What _is_ happening?

Comment: I want to show the name of the dashboard in a table. But when I try it with @{dashboard.currentPage} I don't get the name of the dashboard, I get a 0 back. I don't have any error messages. And I'm not sure if this is the right comand to request the dashboard-name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
@{dashboard.currentPage}
@{dashboard.caption}
```

[image]

For the variable to work, you obviously need to be viewing it on an object that is part of a dashboard.

For a full list of system Presentation Variables and their current values, put the following in a Static Text view. Tick "Contains HTML Markup".

```
[u][b]Predefined Presentation Variables
[/b][/u][br/]
<p align="left">
[b]analysis.report.currency.name:[/b]    @{analysis.report.currency.name}[br/]
[b]analysis.report.currency.symbol:[/b]    @{analysis.report.currency.symbol}[br/]
[b]analysis.report.currency.userPreference:[/b]    @{analysis.report.currency.userPreference}[br/]
[b]dashboard.currentPage.currency.name:[/b]    @{dashboard.currentPage.currency.name}[br/]
[b]dashboard.currentPage.currency.userPreference:[/b]    @{dashboard.currentPage.currency.userPreference}[br/]
[b]dashboard.currentPage.currency.symbol:[/b]    @{dashboard.currentPage.currency.symbol}[br/]
[b]dashboard.currentPage:[/b]    @{dashboard.currentPage}[br/]
[b]dashboard.currentPage.currency.symbol.name:[/b]    @{dashboard.currentPage.currency.symbol.name}[br/]
[b]dashboard.currentPage.currency.symbol.path:[/b]    @{dashboard.currentPage.currency.symbol.path}[br/]
[b]dashboard.author:[/b]    @{dashboard.author}[br/]
[b]dashboard.caption:[/b]    @{dashboard.caption}[br/]
[b]dashboard.currency.name:[/b]    @{dashboard.currency.name}[br/]
[b]dashboard.currency.symbol:[/b]    @{dashboard.currency.symbol}[br/]
[b]dashboard.currency.userPreference:[/b]    @{dashboard.currency.userPreference}[br/]
[b]dashboard.description:[/b]    @{dashboard.description}[br/]
[b]dashboard.location:[/b]    @{dashboard.location}[br/]
[b]dashboard.name:[/b]    @{dashboard.name}[br/]
[b]dashboard.path:[/b]    @{dashboard.path}[br/]
[b]dashboard.xml:[/b]    @{dashboard.xml}[br/]
[b]session.currency.name:[/b]    @{session.currency.name}[br/]
[b]session.currency.symbol:[/b]    @{session.currency.symbol}[br/]
[b]session.currency.userPreference:[/b]    @{session.currency.userPreference}[br/]
[b]session.currentUser:[/b]    @{session.currentUser}[br/]
[b]session.language:[/b]    @{session.language}[br/]
[b]session.lastAccessTime:[/b]    @{session.lastAccessTime}[br/]
[b]session.locale:[/b]    @{session.locale}[br/]
[b]session.loginTime:[/b]    @{session.loginTime}[br/]
[b]session.logoutTime:[/b]    @{session.logoutTime}[br/]
[b]session.rtl:[/b]    @{session.rtl}[br/]
[b]session.timeZone:[/b]    @{session.timeZone}[br/]
[b]session.timeZone.id:[/b]    @{session.timeZone.id}[br/]
[b]session.timeZone.name:[/b]    @{session.timeZone.name}[br/]
[b]session.timeZone.value:[/b]    @{session.timeZone.value}[br/]
[b]system.currentTime:[/b]    @{system.currentTime}[br/]
[b]system.productVersion:[/b]    @{system.productVersion}[br/]
[b]user.displayName:[/b]    @{user.displayName}[br/]
[b]user.homeDirectory:[/b]    @{user.homeDirectory}[br/]
[b]user.id:[/b]    @{user.id}[br/]</p>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I got a ticker now that is positioned on every dashboard page. I can choose which dashboard page gets a ticker message through database entries. Works perfectly and delivers the customers every information they need to know about the dashboards.